# What is the aerodynamic reason military parachutes are square?

Tags: military, parachute

Until these, I had only ever seen round military parachutes. The slots also differ between paratroop
[image: paratroop]

and cargo.
[image: cargo]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The top pic is the new T-11 canopy adopted by the US Army.  Has a significantly lower descent rate and less opening shock compared to the old T-10.

Comment: Does square have anything to do with descent rate, or is it just size?

Comment: It's quite a bit bigger than a T10, hence lower descent rate, and the square shape with vents at the corners limits oscillations, allowing shorter lines and reducing injuries from getting smacked into the ground mid-swing.  There is a slider panel reefing system similar to what's used on ram air parachutes slows the inflation speed.  Supposed to be a huge drop in injury rates, about 3/4.